# Show User Location on Map Failed with API Client Connection Error

Tags: android, location, google-maps-android-api-2, android-googleapiclient

I want to show the user's location on a map whenever a toggle button is pressed. I have written the code like below and it works only to show the map but not the user's location and sometimes throws error like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
```

on this line: `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(apiClient, locationRequest, this);`

I am able to get the location in logcat but can't show on map. Here's the fragment code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

private static final String TAG = HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TextView driverStatusTV;

public static MaterialAnimatedSwitch statusSwitch;
public static GoogleApiClient apiClient;
public static Location mLastLocation;
public static LocationRequest locationRequest;

public GoogleMap mGmap;
public static Marker currentMarker;
public static double latitude = 0f, longitude = 0f;

public static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 15000;
public static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 8000;
public static final int DISPLACEMENT = 10;

public static final int PLAY_SERVICES_REQ_CODE = 9009;
public static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQ_CODE = 9090;

private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private void initViews(View view) {
    toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    driverStatusTV = view.findViewById(R.id.driverStatusTV);
    statusSwitch = view.findViewById(R.id.statusSwitch);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    initViews(view);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    setUpLocation();

    statusSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MaterialAnimatedSwitch.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(boolean b) {
            if (b){
                Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "You are Now Online", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startLocationListener();
                displayLocation();
                driverStatusTV.setText("ONLINE");
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "You are Now Offline", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                stopLocationListener();
                driverStatusTV.setText("OFFLINE");
                //currentMarker.remove();
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case AppConstants.LOC_PERM_CODE:
            for (int gr : grantResults) {
                if (gr == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (checkPlayServices()) {
                        makeLocationRequest();
                        initAPIClient();
                        if (statusSwitch.isChecked()) {
                            displayLocation();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Google Play Services Not Supported on Your Device", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    getActivity().finish();
                    getActivity().moveTaskToBack(true);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

public void startLocationListener() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, AppConstants.LOC_PERM_CODE);
    } else {
        initAPIClient();
        apiClient.connect();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(apiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }
}

public void setUpLocation() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    } else {
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            if (statusSwitch.isChecked()) {
                initAPIClient();
                makeLocationRequest();
                displayLocation();
            }
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Google Play Services Not Supported on Your Device", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

private void makeLocationRequest() {
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
}

public boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, getActivity(), AppConstants.PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Play Services NOT Supported on Your Device", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getActivity().finish();
            getActivity().moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void initAPIClient() {
    apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), 0, this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    apiClient.connect();
}

public void stopLocationListener() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    } else {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(apiClient, this);
    }
}

public void displayLocation() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, AppConstants.LOC_PERM_CODE);
    } else {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(apiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            if (statusSwitch.isChecked()) {
                latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
                Log.d(TAG, "Locn:\t" + "lat:\t" + latitude + "and long:\t" + longitude);

                geoFire.setLocation("saj9oPN15VZODBbB87JXU26Rqa53", new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                        if (currentMarker != null) {
                            currentMarker.remove();
                            currentMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car));
                            currentMarker = mGmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));

                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17f);
                            mGmap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

                            //draw rotate marker animation
                            //rotateMarker(currentMarker, -360, mGmap);

                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }
}

private void rotateMarker(final Marker currentMarker, final float i, GoogleMap mGmap) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final float startRotation = currentMarker.getRotation();
    final int duration = 1500;

    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long elapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation(elapsed / duration);
            float rot = t * i + (1 - t) * startRotation;
            currentMarker.setRotation(-rot > 180 ? rot / 2 : rot);

            if (t < 1.0) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
            }

        }
    }, duration);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    startLocationListener();
    displayLocation();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    apiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (apiClient != null) {
        apiClient = null;
        initAPIClient();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    displayLocation();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGmap = googleMap;
}
```

}

Can anyone help me understand why it's not working.

Comment: Have you correct registered your .SHA fingerprint to use Google Maps Api?

Comment: @statosdotcom, Yes I have added that with package name

Comment: The error is on this line always: LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(apiClient, locationRequest, this);

Comment: You don't have to invoque again `apiClient.connect();` before **LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(apiClient, locationRequest, this)** because it has been called before on `initAPIClient();`. I know, error message says **is not connected yet** then your problem is at another point - cause you are trying to connect 2 times in a row and no connections is done.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because you are using the depreciated interface `FusedLocationProviderApi`.  I see no value to you if I were  to provide an answer to your code which uses the depreciated interface. ::   I strongly suggest that you migrate to `FusedLocationProviderClient`.

Comment: I have removed the duplicate connection attempts and yes, I was also considering using the newer api. Thanks again.